# Finding double root of $x^5-x+\alpha$

Tags: polynomials, roots

Given the polynomial
$$x^5-x+\alpha$$
Find a value of $\alpha>0$ for which the above polynomial has a double root.

Here's an animated plot of the roots as you change $\alpha$ from $0$ to $1$ I'm looking for $\alpha$ when the 2 points in the plot meet.

[image: animation]

Also, this is not homework

Comment: If $p(x)$ has a double root, that is also a root of the derivative $p'(x)$.

Comment: I look forward to several more answers saying essentially the same thing.

Comment: Another approach is to show that the zero of the polynomial located at $x=0$ when $a=0$ is represented by the power series $$x_0 = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\binom{5n}{n}}{4n+1} \alpha^{4n+1}.$$  Within the radius of convergence of this series the zero $x_0$ is simple, so to calculate the value of $|\alpha|$ when $x_0$ collides with another zero we just need to calculate the radius of convergence of the series.

Comment: Nice animation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A multiple root is a common root of both $f(x)$ and $f^{\prime}(x)$.
$$f^{\prime}(x)=5x^4-1$$

and if you are interested only in real roots (i get this impression that you are)

then $$x=\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{5}}$$

and further we must have

$$f\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{5}}\right)=0$$  this gives

$$\alpha=\frac{4}{5\sqrt[4]{5}}$$

Comment: ... and a short proof of the key fact is that if $f(x) = (x-a)^n g(x)$ with $g(a) \neq 0$ and $n \geq 1$, then $f'(x) = (x-a)^{n-1} (n g(x) + (x-a) g'(x))$, and thus $f'(a)$ is zero iff $n > 1$.

Comment: There are two real roots of the derivative.

Comment: @LutzL Thanks for pointing that out. Ill edit.

Comment: On the other hand, since $α>0$ per assumptions, this does not give a new solution.

Comment: @LutzL what are you doing to me ?

Comment: The formulation of the first step is slightly wrong, there are really two real roots $x$ of the derivative. Of the two possible values for $α$ that result from them, only one is positive. Since the formulation is "find **a** value for $α$", one can select to only consider the positive solution for $x$, since it leads to **a** value.

Answer (score 2):

If you write a polynomial $p(x)=(x-r_1)^{n_1}\ldots (x-r_k)^{n_k}$ where we assume each $r_i\ne r_j$ when $i\ne j$ and $n_i\ge 1$ for $1\le i\le k$.

Then if we take derivatives, the product rule gives us

$$p'(x)=\sum_{i=1}^k n_i(x-r_i)^{n_i-1}\prod_{i\ne j}(x-r_j)^{n_j}$$

If $n_m=1$ for some $1\le m\le k$, then we get that $(x-r_m)$ divides each term except one, hence by the rules of divisibility, it cannot divide the sum, hence the derivative does not share this particular root. On the other hand, if $n_m>1$, then $(x-r_m)$ divides every term in that sum, hence the two share that root.

So the common roots of $p(x)$ and $p'(x)$ are exactly the multiple roots of $p$.

As Peter notes, for this case this implies that

$$(x^5-x+\alpha, 5x^4-1)=(5x^4-1, 4x-5\alpha)=(4x-5\alpha, {3125\over 256}\alpha^4-1)$$

so $\alpha^4={256\over 3125}$.

Comment: And then we have $\gcd(x^5 - x + \alpha, 5x^4 - 1)$ $= \gcd(5x^4 - 1, 4x - 5\alpha)$ $= \gcd(4x - 5\alpha, \frac{3125}{256}\alpha^4 - 1)$, so in order for that GCD to be linear we require $\frac{3125}{256}\alpha^4 - 1 = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Somebody posted a hint answer which made solving it easy, but they quickly deleted it. Here's a solution using that answer.

When the [discriminant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant) of a polynomial is zero, atleast two roots coincide.

The discriminant of $x^5-x+\alpha$ is $3125\alpha^4-256$ solving for $\alpha$

$$3125\alpha^4-256=0$$
$$3125\alpha^4=256$$
$$\alpha^4=\frac{256}{3125}$$
$$\alpha=\frac{4}{\sqrt[4]{3125}}$$
$$\alpha=\frac{4}{5\sqrt[4]{5}}$$

Answer (score 1):

As Daniel pointed out, since $p(x)$ will have a double root, $p'(x)$ must have the same root as well.

Also, by using Descartes rules of signs,

$$p(x) = x^5 -x +\alpha$$
$$p(-x) = -x^5 +x +\alpha$$

Therefore, p(x) has either 2 or 0 positive roots, 1 negative root, and either 2 or 4 complex root.

Since we are assumed there is a positive root, $p(x)$ will have 2 positive roots, 1 negative root, and 2 complex roots.

Taking the derivative,

$$p'(x) = 5x^4-1$$

Solving for x, we get that $$x =\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^{\frac{1}{4}}$$

Comment: What we need to find is $\alpha$ not that $x$